# Launch test file (pytest) as debug for active file in VSCode

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code, pytest

I have a python library (module) that contains multiple modules and associated tests following a fairly standard structure

```
project_root
    library_folder
        __init__.py
        module_A
            __init__.py
            sub_module_AA
                __init__.py
                file_AAA.py
            file_AA.py
            file_AB.py
            file_AC.py
        module_B
            __init__.py
            file_BA.py
            file_BB.py
        module_C
            __init__.py
            file_CA.py
            file_CB.py
            file_CC.py
        ...
    tests
        module_A
            test_fileAA.py
            ...
        module_B
            test_fileBA.py
            ...
    pyproject.toml
    ...
```

Currently I am doing what I would call *caveman debugging* by dropping a `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` into a buggy file and then I call the corresponding test with `pytest path/to/test_fileXY.py` and wait for the breakpoint. I would like to move this setup to VSCode so that I can simply hit `F5` and run the corresponding tests.

My problem is that I need to call `pytest {workspaceDir}/tests/{submodule_path}/test_{filename}.py` to run the tests. I can get quite close via

```json
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Run Current File's Tests",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "module": "pytest",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "args": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/tests/${relativeFileDirname}/test_${fileBasename}"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

However, this produces `{workspaceDir}/tests/library_folder/{submodule_path}/test_{filename}.py` (note the additional `library_folder` in the path. How do I do this correctly, i.e., how do I create a reference to the active file's corresponding test?

Answer (score 1):

The python extension has build-in this feature:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I am aware of this feature and it is also quite close but doesn't work for me. The option `Python: Debug All Tests` doesn't work for me, because my test suite is too big making debugging undesirably slow. Running the individual tests via CodeLense works, but being located above the tests means I need to go dig for them and switch tabs each time. I'm currently trying it via the sidebar menu, but a setup where I can make a small change and press a "did I shoot myself in the foot? (run local tests)" button seems much more elegant.